# Users can sent alerts to police and trusted contacts in emergency

Tags: grammar

Is the sentence correct grammatically? If yes, Is it correct to place simple past(V2) or past participle(V3) form of verb after modals (can,could,will,would....). As per my understanding after modals the verb should be in its base form. But in the sentence"Users can ***sent*** alerts to police and trusted contacts in emergency", the verb is in its past form.

Comment: What is the source of the sentence?  Please tell us exactly where you read this.  If possible, link to the source in your question.

Comment: It is an article in the THE HINDU newspaper edition.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, and the sentence is not. As you said, it should be:

> Users can **send** alerts to ...

Comment: But it is a newspaper article heading. So it is incorrect in the publication.

Comment: @RAVIVARMA Yes, it is incorrect. Newspapers are not infallible.